# Delete a file from smart card

Tags: embedded, smartcard, scosta

Is it possible in Scosta Complient OS for smart card,to delete a file which is in creation state ?

Comment: Please followup on your questions anand - what's wrong with the answer of guidot?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, there is no special mention of life cycle phases in the COSTA specification, especially not in the delete file section. In that case I would assume ISO 7816-9 to hold, which only requires access rules to be evaluated in OPERATIONAL ACTIVE and OPERATION DEACTIVATED. The state diagram, does NOT have an arrow from Creation state to non-existing, so situation is likely to be OS-dependent. But if supported, there is some chance, that the file in CREATION phase can always be deleted, at least if the rules for Delete Child of the containing DF and Delete Self of the file in question are fulfilled (as mandated by Costa generally), it may well work.